# Stokes' Theorem Questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There are a couple of things that confuse me with Stokes' Theorem

1) What's the difference between d**S** and d**A** and how is it used?

2) What's the difference between $\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{k}}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{n}}}$ and how is it used?

Thanks

Comment: If you're interested in Stokes' theorem it may be useful to read about the [differential forms approach](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf).  Or here is something (not quite as good, but it should work) on the [vectorial approach](http://www.msc.uky.edu/droyster/courses/spring98/math2242/classnotes6.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d\mathbf S$ is used to denote $\mathbf n \cdot dS$ where $\mathbf n$ is the orthonormal vector to the surface and $dS$ is element of surface area.

$dA$ is element of area (I refer to differential as element because it's more intuitive).

$\mathbf{\hat{k}}$ is the unit vector $\langle0,0,1\rangle$, and $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit vector perpendicular to the surface (there are two of them, you work with the one you need).

Stokes' Theorem reads:

$$\oint_C \mathbf Fd\mathbf r= \iint_S \text{curl}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\iint_S \text{curl}\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n \,dS. \tag{1}$$

If you have a parameterization of the surface $\mathbf T(u,v)$ then it is easy to see that for each point on the surface, there is a normal vector $\mathbf n^*=\mathbf T_u\times\mathbf T_v.$ But $dS=\|\mathbf n^*\|dA$. Note that $dA$ refers to the domain of the transformation (or parameterization) $\mathbf T$. This means that $(1)$ yields

$$\iint_D \text{curl}\mathbf F \cdot \frac{\mathbf n^*}{\|\mathbf n^*\|}\|\mathbf n^*\|\,dA.$$

Comment: Why does dS = ndA?

Comment: @Gabriel it's notation. You are interested in the flux through $S$ so you multiply $dA$ times $\mathbf n$ because you are interested in the projection of $\mathbf F$ onto $\mathbf n$.

Comment: Do the $\|\mathbf n^*\|$'s always cancel out? Meaning, can we write Stokes' Theorem as $\oint_C \mathbf Fd\mathbf r= \iint_S \text{curl}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\iint_S \text{curl}\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n \,dS = \iint_R curl\mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n dA$ in all cases?

Comment: @Gabriel whenever you can parameterize the surface, yes.

Comment: Can you ever not parametrize a surface?

Comment: @Gabriel [look here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/workshop2007/van_luijk_changed.pdf)